# Clarification needed on React's JSX syntax

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am learning to code in React and bit confused with JSX syntax.

I tried to understand but getting confused again and again.
It will be better if someone explains to me what exactly happening here with this code and what is the problem.

Here I am trying to iterate over form element array with below code:

```
const form = formElementArray.map(element =>{ 
     <Input 
        key = {element.id} 
        elementType={element.config.elementType}
        elementConfig={element.config.elementConfig} 
        value={element.config.value}
        inValid = {!element.config.valid}
        touched = {element.config.touched}
        changed={(event)=>this.onChangeHandler(event,element.id)}
        shouldValidate={element.config.validation}>
    </Input>
})
```

> Error: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.

Comment: you need `return` before the `Input` element or remove { } after the arrow

Answer (score 0):

when using arrow function can emit the `return` keyword when you don't provide open/close brackets.

to fix remove `{` and `}` from your arrow function

```
const form = formElementArray.map(element => 
                     <Input 
                        key = {element.id} 
                        elementType={element.config.elementType}
                        elementConfig={element.config.elementConfig} 
                        value={element.config.value}
                        inValid = {!element.config.valid}
                        touched = {element.config.touched}
                        changed={(event)=>this.onChangeHandler(event,element.id)}
                        shouldValidate={element.config.validation}>
                        </Input>
                )
```

Comment: Yes, I agree that will fix the issue. when I am doing it without curly brackets, what it is returning from the map? Does it return the list like '<Input..../> <Input.../><Input.../>' and assign it to const form ?

Answer (score 0):

**JSX expression:**

```
{<div>some html tag with one root tags. wrapping brackets { and } </div>}
```

JSX means JavaScript XML. that says, you can write html in your JavaScript file.
**Arrow function:**

```
const randomFunc1 = (param) => {
  var data = 'some data' + param;
  return data;
}
OR
const randomFunc2 = param => {
  var data = 'some data' + param;
  return data;
}
OR
const randomFunc3 = param => 'some data' + param;
```

Above `randomFunc1`, `randomFunc2`, `randomFunc3` doing same as one. `randomFunc3` is the shortest syntax.

Your code is ok. but map function needs to return statement to create a new array. so just need a `return` keyword before `<Input>` tag